# How to loop through components with same prop

Tags: react-native

I have several TextInputs with the prop 'form' to identify the forms they belong to.

```
<TextInput form="user" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name"/>
<TextInput form="user" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name"/>
<TextInput form="login" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
```

How do I loop through components that have the prop form="user", in this case I would want to get *first_name* and *last_name* and leave out *username*.

Comment: I recommend reading this documentation chapter: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-text-input.html - what you're trying to do is not an idiomatic React pattern

Comment: can you add the requirement on why you want to loop over the components?